# How to read a specific port with ADC in Mplab Harmony?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplabx, mplab-harmony

I configured the ADC for 3 instances/3 analog inputs:

[image]
[image]

```
In APP_STATE_INIT i enable and start ADC:

    case APP_STATE_INIT:
    {
        bool appInitialized = true;


        if (appInitialized)
        {

            appData.state = APP_STATE_SERVICE_TASKS;
        }
        DRV_TMR0_Start(); // Start the Timers
        DRV_ADC_Initiallize();
        DRV_ADC_Enable();
    }
```

Now in this test application I want to read the ports.
But in this specific case I want to read the Channel Instance 0 and Instance 1 (each instance will have changing values that can be configured with a dil-switch):

```
    case APP_STATE_SERVICE_TASKS:
    {
        DRV_ADC_Start();
        //Provide Delay
        int i;
        for(i=0;i <1000;i++)
        {
        }
        DRV_ADC_Stop();
        while(!DRV_ADC_SamplesAvailable()) {}
        printf("addr: %d \r\n",DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(i)>>2);
        break;
    }
```

This is alternating between values when it's not supposed. I configured 3 channels so I suppose it's alternating between them, how to choose a specific channel?

What needs to be done here?

The pins are configured this way:

[image]
[image]

Basically what i would like is something like we have in the **pic32 family reference manual** in
**Example 17-1: Converting 1 Channel, Manual Sample Start, Manual Conversion Start Code**

```
 AD1PCFG = 0xFFFB; // PORTB = Digital; RB2 = analog
 AD1CON1 = 0x0000; // SAMP bit = 0 ends sampling ...
 // and starts converting
 AD1CHS = 0x00020000; // Connect RB2/AN2 as CH0 input ..
 // in this example RB2/AN2 is the input
 AD1CSSL = 0;
 AD1CON3 = 0x0002; // Manual Sample, Tad = internal 6 TPB
 AD1CON2 = 0;
 AD1CON1SET = 0x8000; // turn ADC ON
 while (1) // repeat continuously
 {
     AD1CON1SET = 0x0002;         // start sampling ...
     DelayNmSec(100);             // for 100 mS
     AD1CON1CLR = 0x0002;         // start Converting
     while (!(AD1CON1 & 0x0001)); // conversion done?
     ADCValue = ADC1BUF0;         // yes then get ADC value
 }
```

Where we can choose between channel 14,15 and 22.

Note: It seems to work well if i only have 1 instance running.
This probably has something to do with the multiplex which i dont fully understand.

Using:

- MPLAB Harmony v2
- MPLAB X IDE v5.20
- PIC32MX470F512L configured to run at 32MHz

EDIT:
After applying @pm101 answer it still keeps reading what is not supposed.
[image]

As we can see on termite:
[image]

Doing the other solution:

```
int conversion;
uint8_t j = 0;
while(j++<3) {
    DRV_ADC_Start();        
    //Provide Delay
        int i;
        for(i=0;i <1000;i++)
        {
        }    
    while(!DRV_ADC_SamplesAvailable()) {}
}
DRV_ADC_Stop();
conversion = DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(val)>>2;//Val will be the sample we want to read.
return (unsigned char)conversion;
```

The value is always the same?

TEST 19/06

I did the following to my ADC_GetConversion function:

```
unsigned char ADC_GetConversion(uint8_t val){ 
    int conversion;
    switch(val) {
        case 0:
            AD1CSSLCLR = 0x00000000;
            AD1CSSLSET = 0x00004000;//AN14
            break;            
        case 1:
            AD1CSSLCLR = 0x00000000;
            AD1CSSLSET = 0x00008000;//AN15
            break;
    }
    DRV_ADC_Start();        
        //Provide Delay
        int i;
        for(i=0;i <1000;i++)
        {
        }    
       while(!DRV_ADC_SamplesAvailable()) {}
    DRV_ADC_Stop();
conversion = DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(0)>>2;
return (unsigned char)conversion;
}
```

then on a while cycle i do:

```
printf("addr%d: %d \r\n",14,decode_switch_conversion(ADC_GetConversion(0)));
printf("addr%d: %d \r\n",15,decode_switch_conversion(ADC_GetConversion(1)));
```

Context: The `decode_switch_conversion` converts these adc tension conversion to the correspondent value that was coded in a four switch (only switch number 1 down means we want the value 1) . AN14 there is connected a 4 switch, and the AN15 there is another 4 four switch.

But those 2 prints get the value switched for both?
The result i get from termite:
[image]

In reality i have 1 for the switch of AN14 and 3 for the switch of AN15.

But if i only read 1 channel and never do the lines AD1CSSLCLR and AD1CSSLSET the values are good!

Comment: You have asked a ton of questions very closely related, which is fine. But, is there no company provided training to get to up to speed with working with these tools?

Comment: Hi @Tyler, on my company which have a small R&D team there is no one that works with these framework, anyhow I have not found on the internet a satisfactory answer to this problem, so I posted the question here in hope it can help me and anyone who searches for the same.

Comment: Anyway @Tyler what i've did seems to work to a certain point, i just need to find how i can do a new scan on a pin.

Comment: @Nmaster88 Harmony comes installed with a load of example projects. You should look at them

Comment: @Oscillonoscope i haven't find what i need/want on the example that was on my installation of harmony.

Comment: Posting 2-3 of these questions each day after day isn't really how this site is supposed to be used; you need to get better about reading manuals, doing your own research and consulting examples - *this is not a custom tutorial generation service*.  This has already been pointed out to you, so if you're going to keep doing it, so you'll need to get used to being downvoted (the hover text on the downvote button specifically mentions insufficient research effort)

Comment: @ChrisStratton i've been searching for the last days about this, if i'm asking about it is because i haven't found a way to make it work. Anyway i'm going to be more selective on the questions i post here. If anyone can help with this it will be much appreciatted.

Comment: What if you change the settings from Scan Channel to Dedicated Channel ?

Comment: Hi @efox29 i tried with dedicated and from what i remember didn't work, why?

Comment: I suggest that you eliminate all unnecessary variables and configure harmony to only sample one ADC channel. To get it started, perhaps you can configure it to sample the internal band gap or reference (most PICs have them I believe). Have you checked the datasheet to see what the necessary steps are and then checked your registers with a debugger before you sample, that all registers are set correctly ? If you dont have debugger, the simulator would be good enough to check register values.

Comment: @efox29 i think i found the right code for me in pic32 family reference manual, i only want a function that i call it with the channel as argument and get it's ADC reading. Now if Harmony on it's harmony as functions for its good, if not i will try to replicate whats on the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think the Harmony examples for ADC are poor.

Harmony automatically adds your channels to the scan list in `DRV_ADC_Initialize` with the function `PLIB_ADC_InputScanMaskAdd` so you shouldn't need to do that again.

I think what you are looking for is actually what you are using (`DRV_ADC_SamplesRead`) but not using it correctly.

If you look at the harmony source code for this function , the prototype is `ADC_SAMPLE DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(uint8_t bufIndex)` . You might also notice that this is just a wrapper function for `PLIB_ADC_ResultGetByIndex` see [Harmony Libraries guide page 55-56](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Peripheral%20Libraries_v111.pdf).

It requires a buffer index as a parameter. The buffer index however is not the same as the channel index. see [DS61104E-page 40](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/61104e.pdf)

The buffer index will probably be the following as they are in order from ANxx and in your scan mask set up by Harmony.

```
0 AN14 
1 AN15 
2 AN22
```

You will need to take three readings. You will need to call `DRV_ADC_Start` before each scan to overwrite the buffer. You will also need to enable the ADC before starting using `DRV_ADC_Open`

Also I wouldn't stop the ADC until `DRV_ADC_SamplesAvailable()` returns non zero.

So the steps are

1. DRV_ADC_Open()
2. DRV_ADC_Start()
3. wait until DRV_ADC_SamplesAvailable() is true . Go back to 2 until 3 channels read
4. DRV_ADC_Stop()
5. AN14 = `DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(0)`
6. AN15 = `DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(1)`
7. AN22 = `DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(2)`

You may either implement as a state machine or use while loop to wait on samples available.

But this isn't a proper scan. To do a scan, you need to set ASAM which (Harmony functions don't appear to do?) There is a PLIB function, but I'd just do the following

First Set :

AD1CON2bits.SMPI = 2

This will set the interrupt flag high when scan has converted three readings
I made a function below:

```
void ADC_StartScan ( unsigned char numChannels )
{
   IFS0bits.ADIF = 0; // reset interrupt flag
   AD1CON2bits.SMPI = numChannels-1; // set number of channels to sample before interrupt flag goes high
   AD1CON1bits.ASAM = 1; // start scan
   while (!IFS0bits.ADIF); // wait for interrupt flag
   AD1CON1bits.ASAM = 0; // stop scan
}
```

(see page 52 of DS61104E)

Usage

```
ADC_StartScan(3);

AN14 = DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(0);
AN15 = DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(1);
AN22 = DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(2);
```

*Disclaimer: Pure research and no coding done*

Personally I'd use dedicated channel as it's probably easier to work with, Some example code I found with nice state machine [here](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/232598/app.c)

Comment: Hi @pm101 thanks for answer, in DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(0) if i read the same number it will alternate between the values on the different channels.

Comment: It could be that you'll need to do steps 2 and 3, 3 times, see page 41 of  DS61104E. When SAMP is high, the next in the scan is chosen. `DRV_ADC_Start` only sets SAMP high, not ASAM. Because you're in poll mode this might be the only way. Typically scanning is done in interrupts.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide some polling scan code. I agree that harmony's ADC implementation is rather poorly documented for beginners.

Comment: That seems nice, but still it's taking the wrong reading? if i'm in a while always reading DRV_ADC_SamplesRead(0). Thank you so much.

Comment: maybe we can't mix plib code with harmony code?

Comment: I configured only one sample per interrupt if thats worth for anything.

Comment: If you configure only one sample per interrupt it will only read the first channel each time.

Comment: i'm going to give you the bounty for the effort, still when i have time i will compare the basic code i have now with harmony code to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You had to trigger each sample on its own. Here is a really good explanation of the complete Harmony ADC API here: [ADC peripheral library interface](https://microchipdeveloper.com/harmony:adc) with examples.

I guess you are looking for a function like:

```
int readADC(intchannel)
```

You had to write such a function on your own, but it should be really easy with the example from the datasheet.

Comment: these seems the function i want DRV_ADC_InputsRegister: This function causes the driver to select a set of input registers for sampling. But it's not in my ```drv_adc_static.c``` i have there DRV_ADC_ChannelScanInputsAdd and DRV_ADC_ChannelScanInputsRemove.

Answer (score 0):

For now i implemented ADC the same way that MCC configures it. So in `SYS_Initialize` i have:

```
/*Initialize ADC */
// ASAM disabled; DONE disabled; CLRASAM disabled; FORM Integer 16 bit; SAMP disabled; SSRC Clearing sample bit ends sampling and starts conversion; SIDL disabled; ON enabled; 
AD1CON1 = 0x8000;

// CSCNA disabled; ALTS disabled; BUFM disabled; SMPI 1; OFFCAL disabled; VCFG AVDD/AVSS; 
AD1CON2 = 0x0;

// SAMC 0; ADRC PBCLK; ADCS 0; 
AD1CON3 = 0x0;

// CH0SA AN14; CH0SB AN15; CH0NB Vrefl; CH0NA Vrefl; 
AD1CHS = 0xF0E0000;

// CSSL26 disabled; CSSL25 disabled; CSSL28 disabled; CSSL27 disabled; CSSL22 disabled; CSSL21 disabled; CSSL24 disabled; CSSL9 disabled; CSSL23 disabled; CSSL20 disabled; CSSL0 disabled; CSSL8 disabled; CSSL7 disabled; CSSL6 disabled; CSSL5 disabled; CSSL4 disabled; CSSL3 disabled; CSSL29 disabled; CSSL2 disabled; CSSL1 disabled; CSSL15 disabled; CSSL14 disabled; CSSL17 disabled; CSSL16 disabled; CSSL11 disabled; CSSL10 disabled; CSSL13 disabled; CSSL12 disabled; CSSL30 disabled; CSSL19 disabled; CSSL18 disabled; 
AD1CSSL = 0x0;
```

Then in my `ADC_GetConversion` function:

```
unsigned char ADC_GetConversion(uint8_t val){ 
    int conversion;
    uint32_t channel;
    switch(val) {
        case 0:
            channel = 0xE; // ADR1 AN14
            break;            
        case 1:
            channel = 0xF; // ADR2 AN15
            break;            
        case 2:
            channel = 0x16; //DEVICE RESPONSE AN22
            break;
    }
    AD1CHS = channel << 16;
    AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 1;       
    //Provide Delay
    int i;
    for(i=0;i <1000;i++)
    {
    }
    AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 0; 
    while(!AD1CON1bits.DONE) {
        if(IFS0bits.AD1IF)
        {
            // Read ADC Buffer since the interrupt is persistent

            // clear ADC interrupt flag
            IFS0CLR= 1 << _IFS0_AD1IF_POSITION;
        }
    }

      conversion = ADC1BUF0 >> 2;
     return (unsigned char)conversion;
}
```

At least for now this will do.

I can't understand how ADC is so hard to configure with Harmony, it seems a lot easier to simply go to the datasheet i copy the base code.

Comment: As long as this works, you can integrate it with your harmony code no problem. Just be careful of too much blocking code, you could implement a state machine. I think the fact it has been set up for single channel rather than scan mode here makes it easier. With your 'scan' and 'poll' set up it is done differently and the harmony functions don't seem to be easily understandable for getting scans to work in poll mode.